# Oracle 10g Inner Join with Limit clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, inner-join, limit

I feel like this *should* be easy, but i am struggling to return the top result from an inner join select. This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM PROCESS_OWNER.ARTIFACTS, PROCESS_OWNER.ARTIFACT_METADATA
    WHERE ARTIFACTS.ARTIFACT_ID = ARTIFACT_METADATA.ARTIFACT_ID
    AND ARTIFACTS.ARTIFACT_LABEL = 'getDBStatus'
    ORDER BY ARTIFACTS.REGISTERED_TIMESTAMP DESC 
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Database is Oracle 10g. The error i get is: 00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

The inner query works fine - returing some 38 records ordered by TIMESTAMP, i just want the most recent (top one)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner query returns two columns called ARTIFACT_ID - one from each table.  When you nest that in another select, it results in the error you see.  You need to unambiguously list the columns you want in the inner select.

Oddly, it appears that if you re-write it with an ANSI join, it works:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM PROCESS_OWNER.ARTIFACTS
    JOIN PROCESS_OWNER.ARTIFACT_METADATA
    ON ARTIFACTS.ARTIFACT_ID = ARTIFACT_METADATA.ARTIFACT_ID
    WHERE ARTIFACTS.ARTIFACT_LABEL = 'getDBStatus'
    ORDER BY ARTIFACTS.REGISTERED_TIMESTAMP DESC 
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Very odd though that it works this way... One last thing - The two ARTIFACT_ID columns are returned as "QCSJ_C0000000000004000001" and "QCSJ_C0000000000004000000" is there anyway i can rename them (or atleast one)?

Comment: You are back to having to specify **all** the column names you want in the inner query.

Answer (score 2):

There must be a column that is common (in name) to both ATRIFACTS and ARTIFACT_METADATA.

This is OK in the inner query itself but when the outer query comes to assign names to the columns there is a conflict.

Try naming the inner query columns specifically (naming the similarly named columns something distinct) and it should work OK.

Better still, only select the columns you absolutely need in the inner query rather than SELECT *

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was afriad of having to name the columns explicitly - this works but is a right pain. Is there no better way? Would using row_number() / an analytic function make any difference?

Comment: @Ryan: Try re-writing with ANSI JOIN syntax - see my updated answer.

Comment: Other than Tony finding you can use an ANSI syntax join, you could use a correlated subquery but that would incur additional overheads.

Comment: @Tony, nice one, I hadn't thought that re-writing using ANSI syntax would make a difference.

Comment: Nor did I.  My intention was to try using the USING () syntax, but found it worked before I got that far!